# Where is unread cin input stored?

Tags: c++

If I enter a string "Hello World" using cin then where will "World" be stored? How can I ignore that string ("World")?

If the string ("World") is stored in the buffer then I can't remove that using `std::endl`.

Comment: Please make a [mre] and describe the issue clearly.

Answer (score 3):

The "World" is stored in the buffer. Ignore it with `cin.ignore(5);` (the arguments depend on the text that you want to ignore, e. g. to ignore the next line in the buffer use `cin.ignore(numeric_limits::max(), ‘\n’)`).

**Example 1 (Not using `cin.ignore()`)**

Program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string str1;
    cin >> str1;
    cout << "str1 is " << str1 << "\n";
    string str2;
    cin >> str2;
    cout << "str2 is " << str2 << "\n";
}
```

Input:
Hello world

Output:
"str1 is Hello
str2 is world"

(As we can see `"world"` stayed in the buffer and `str2` took the value without asking as again for `std::cin`).

**Example 2 (Using `cin.ignore()`)**

Program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string str1;
    cin >> str1;
    cout << "str1 is " << str1 << "\n";
    cin.ignore(5); //Just added this line!
    string str2;
    cin >> str2;
    cout << "str2 is " << str2 << "\n";
}
```

Input:
Hello world

Output:
"str1 is Hello"

(As we can see now `"world"` has been ignored and it stays asking us for input in the second `std::cin`).